# Extract data from a substring

Tags: python, substring

I have string like

```
component:test AND SI:test1 AND status:success
```

From the above string how can I need to retrieve the following?

- component:test
- SI:test1

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in split function to split the string by keyword AND which will return a list
For eg:

```
myStr = "component:test AND SI:test1 AND status:success"
myStr.split("AND")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using string `split()`

you can try this may be it's help:

```
s = "component:test AND SI:test1 AND status:success"
s.split("AND")
```

output :

```
['component:test ', ' SI:test1 ', ' status:success']
```

its output help you can access "`'component:test' 'SI:test1'`"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex

```
>>>import re

>>> re.search(r'(.*) AND (.*) AND', myStr).group(1)
'component:test'

>>> re.search(r'(.*) AND (.*) AND', myStr).group(2)
'SI:test1'
```